composition is meromorphic implies that $f(z)$ is also meromorphic on $\mathbb{C}$.

Let $f(z)$ be functions on $\mathbb{C}$ with only isolated singularities, $g(z)$ is a meromorphic function on $\mathbb{C}$ , not a constant . Prove that if $g[f(z)]$ is meromorphic on $\mathbb{C}$, then  $f(z)$ is also meromorphic on $\mathbb{C}$.

My atttempt. We only need to prove that $f$ has no essential singularity. If not, some $z_0$ is an essential singularity of $f$, then the range $f$ of any neighorbhood of $z$ is dense in $\Bbb C$, then what?
the range $g\circ f$ of any neighorbhood of $z$ is dense in $\Bbb C$? Then $z_0$ is an essential singularity of $g\circ f$? A contradiction! Why?

You are almost there. Suppose $f$ is not meromorphic, say $f$ has got an essential singularity at $z_0$. Then, for any $w \in \mathbb{C}$ it is possible to construct a sequence $\{z_n\}$ converging to $z_0$ such that $f(z_n)$ converges to $w$.
Notice that $g\circ f(z_n) \to g\circ f (z_0)$. At the same time, $g(f(z_n)) \to g(w)$. Thus, for all $w\in \mathbb{C}$, $g(w) = g\circ f (z_0)$. This implies that either $g$ is constant (if $g\circ f(z_0)$ is defined) or $g(z)$ is undefined everywhere in the complex plane (if $g\circ f (z_0)$ is undefined). Both cannot happen
